# Cannot access a disposed object. Sockets C#

Tags: c#, .net

I use sockets, and when I try to close the socket, I get an

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.Socket'.

exception.

```
        socket.Close();
        socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  <- exception
```

Why is this happening? why does the garbage collector clean it out?

Comment: Per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.close?view=netcore-3.1)  _for connection-oriented protocols, it is recommended that you call `Shutdown` before calling the `Close` method._ Before, not the after

Comment: As per @Pavel , you can't reference something that you've just got rid of!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remarks section of [`Socket.Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.close?view=netcore-3.1) documentation tells you

> For connection-oriented protocols, it is recommended that you call
>   `Shutdown` before calling the `Close` method. This ensures that all data
>   is sent and received on the connected socket before it is closed.

So, you should call `Shutdown` **before** `Close`, not the after

```cs
socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
socket.Close();
```

Comment: @STALER does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 3):

`Close` is effectively synonymous with `Dispose` in many cases. In the case of a socket, you should use `Shutdown` *before* `Close`/`Dispose` (or not at all).